# Socket closed error after one command in bluetooth and voice recognition application

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, voice-recognition, msp430

I am developing an application that can connect to a bluetooth module (HC06 in my case). in this app i want to send a command to light up 2 leds on my MSP430 board. I managed to connect to the bluetooth  module and say a command ("on" for example). after one command the app has errors and exits.
Note: if i say "on" i want to sent the letter "A", "off" letter "B" and so on.

I seem to have a problem with the socket closing, and that is why i cannot say a second command.
Here is my code:

```
public class VoiceRecognitionDemo extends Activity
{

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private static final String TAG = "SuperAPPLICATIE";
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;
private static final UUID MY_UUID =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
// Insert your bluetooth devices MAC address
private static final String address = "98:D3:31:30:3C:A5";

/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);

    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

    //wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Disable button if no recognition service is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (activities.size() == 0)
    {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }
}

/**
 * Handle the action of the button being clicked
 */
public void speakButtonClicked(View v)
{
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();

}

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}


public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onResume - Attempting client connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.
    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting to Remote...");
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connection established and data link opened...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Creating Socket...");

    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    if (outStream != null) {
        try {
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    try     {
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        //       matches));
        String resulttext = matches.get(0);
        // wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        //   Integer.parseInt(matches.get(0))));

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resulttext, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        String letter;
        switch (resulttext.toLowerCase()) {
            case "on":
                letter = "A";
                break;
            case "off":
                letter = "B";
                break;
            case "flash":
                letter = "F";
                break;
            default:
                letter = "X";
                break;
        }
        sendData(letter.toUpperCase());

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

    Log.d(TAG, "...Sending data: " + message + "...");
    Log.d(TAG, "...In onResume - Attempting client connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.
    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting to Remote...");
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connection established and data link opened...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Creating Socket...");

    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
        if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
            msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 37 in the java code";
        msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    if (outStream != null) {
        try {
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    try     {
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    msg.show();
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Sockets don't just close themselves spontaneously. `SocketException: Socket closed` means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use its. It's a bug in your code.

Your code is very poorly structured. All those strings of try/catch blocks. Code that depends on the success of a prior `try` block should be inside that block. Don't write code like this.